# Combine git rev-list with git show

Tags: git, show, git-rev-list

Currently to review commits made on a branch I do the following:

```
git merge-base HEAD master  # to get the hash of when the branch came off parent
git show [hash from above command]..my-branch
```

However, this lists the commits in reverse chronological order.  I would like to review the commits starting with the first and ending with most recent.  To get the commit hashes in this order one can use

```
git rev-list [hash from above command]..my-branch
```

but could anyone tell me how I can pass this to show or difftool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is actually available directly from `git log`

```
    git log -p --reverse [hash from above command]..my-branch
```